# Formatting multiple phone numbers with Parenthesis[ () ] and hyphen( - ) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a result set in SQL and which contains set of phone numbers with comma separated, earlier we had only one phone number and I could able to format the phone numbers I need i.e.

```
(123)456-7890
```

Now this formula doesn't work since I have more than 10 digits in my SQL column, so is there any way I can achieve this transaction in `SQL`? Here is my SQL output.
[image]

Btw I am getting this `comma separated` value from this code.

```
SELECT
EmployeeID,
Type,
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
        ', ' + PhoneNumber
    FROM EmpPhone E
    WHERE E.EmployeeID = T.EmployeeID AND E.Type = T.Type
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1, ''
) AS Phones
INTO #PhoneNumbers
    FROM EmpPhone AS T
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, Type
```

so my question is can the query result be made like

```
(919)382-9999,(888)888-8888,(222)-2222 ......
```

Comment: My strong advice would be to normalize your data and get those CSV phone numbers spread out in separate records.  Even the formatting you have in mind might be cumbersome, but doable, with normalized data.  In its current format, you are looking at a headache.

Comment: I agree, earlier I wasn't formatting the phone numbers in sql, I was doing that in Crystal Report, now I thought instead of writing a code in Crystal Report I thought let me do it in SQL since StorProc is very short and I may not any performance degrade by implementing this here.

Comment: Search for exploding CSV in SQL Server.  I seem to recall several questions on SO which cover that pretty well.

Comment: btw I cannot spread the record since this is what I need as output to display in CR, so just for formatting the phone numbers I would not expect to change in StorProc.

Comment: the data is already normalized, it is being compressed into a comma separated string for output, so just perform the string manipulation BEFORE you compress the data using that "for xml path" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT
EmployeeID,
Type,
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
        ', ' + '('+LEFT(PhoneNumber,3)+')'+RIGHT(LEFT(PhoneNumber,6),3)+'-'+RIGHT(PhoneNumber,4)
    FROM EmpPhone E
    WHERE E.EmployeeID = T.EmployeeID AND E.Type = T.Type
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1, ''
) AS Phones
INTO #PhoneNumbers
    FROM EmpPhone AS T
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, Type
```

Hope, this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like charm :) I thought I was there to fix this but this really helped my time.